# VBA Code Acting like a Fuzzy vs. Exact Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below. I want it to sort data from Column X in the LeadData tab and sort it as shown below in the different sections on the POI Buckets tab. Now the macro works without error, but is not shorting with right categorization.

Wondering what I Could be doing wrong. I haven't worked in VB/VBA in more than 10 years but I'm doing this to helps someone out.

I am also attaching the file for you to see

```
Sub SortDataIntoPOIBuckets()
    ' Part 1: Initial Setup
    Dim wsLeadData As Worksheet, wsPOIBuckets As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, col As Long
    Dim poi As String
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set wsLeadData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lead Data")
    Set wsPOIBuckets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POI Buckets")
    
    ' Find the last row of data in the Lead Data tab
    lastRow = wsLeadData.Cells(wsLeadData.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).row
    
    ' Clear previous data from POI Buckets starting from row 2
    wsPOIBuckets.Rows("2:" & wsPOIBuckets.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    ' Loop through each row in Lead Data
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Get the product of interest from column X
        poi = wsLeadData.Cells(i, 24).value
        
        ' Determine the column based on POI
        Select Case True
    ' Dialysis Category
    Case poi = "Dialysis", poi = "SpectraFlo™ Dynamic Dialysis Systems", _
         poi = "SpectraPor Tubing Closures", poi = "Dialysis;SpectraFlo™ Dynamic Dialysis Systems", _
         poi = "SpectraPor Float-A-Lyzer", poi = "SpectraPor Micro Float-A-Lyzer"
        col = 1 ' Column A for Dialysis
                
                  
            ' ELISA Category
            Case poi = "ELISA", poi = "ELISA Kits"
                col = 2 ' Column B for ELISA
            
            ' FLOWVPE Category
            Case poi = "FLOWVPE"
                col = 3 ' Column C for FLOWVPE
            
            ' FlowVPX Category
            Case poi = "FlowVPX"
                col = 4 ' Column D for FlowVPX
            
            ' Fluid Management Category
            Case poi = "Fluid Management", poi = "Single-use Valves", _
                 poi = "Single-use Bottles and Containers", poi = "Molded Components and Tubing", _
                 poi = "Non-metallic Process Equipment"
                col = 5 ' Column E for Fluid Management
            
            ' KrosFlo FS Systems Category
            Case poi = "KrosFlo FS Systems", poi = "KrosFlo FS TFF Systems", _
                 poi = "KrosFlo FS 500"
                col = 6 ' Column F for KrosFlo FS Systems
            
            ' Growth Factors Category
            Case poi = "Growth Factors", poi = "LONG R³ IGF-I Cell Culture Supplement", _
                 poi = "LONG EGF Cell Culture Supplement"
                col = 7 ' Column G for Growth Factors
            
            ' Hollow Fibers Category
            Case poi = "Hollow Fibers", poi = "Hollow Fiber Filters", _
                 poi = "X04-E65U-07-N", poi = "N02-E010-10-S", _
                 poi = "Spectrum Hollow Fiber Membranes", poi = "K02-E005-05-N", _
                 poi = "N06-E500-05-S", poi = "N02-P20U-10-N", _
                 poi = "K06-P20U-10-N", poi = "Spectrum Hollow Fiber Filter Modules", _
                 poi = "N02-E100-05-N", poi = "N06-E750-05-N", _
                 poi = "N04-E65U-07-N", poi = "N06-E300-10-N", _
                 poi = "N04-E050-05-N", poi = "N04-E500-05-N", _
                 poi = "K06-E750-10-S", poi = "N02-P20U-05-N", _
                 poi = "X06-E010-05-N", poi = "N04-E030-05-N", _
                 poi = "N04-S010-05-N", poi = "N02-E300-05-S", _
                 poi = "N02-E750-10-N", poi = "K04-E300-05-S", _
                 poi = "N04-E100-05-S", poi = "X05-E300-05-N", _
                 poi = "N04-P20U-10-N", poi = "K04-E500-05-N", _
                 poi = "X04-E500-05-S", poi = "N04-E300-05-S", _
                 poi = "K06-E005-10-S", poi = "K06-E300-10-S", _
                 poi = "K02-E070-10-N", poi = "N02-E050-05-S", _
                 poi = "X05-E65U-07-S", poi = "K06-E050-10-N", _
                 poi = "X10-E500-10-N", poi = "N06-E100-05-N", _
                 poi = "K02-E030-10-N", poi = "N06-E300-05-S", _
                 poi = "N06-S010-05-S", poi = "N02-E100-05-S"
                col = 8 ' Column H for Hollow Fibers
            
            ' KF Comm Category
            Case poi = "KF Comm 2 Software"
                col = 9 ' Column I for KF Comm
            
            ' KMPi Systems Category
            Case poi = "KMPi Systems", poi = "KrosFlo KMPi TFF System", _
                 poi = "KrosFlo KMPi"
                col = 10 ' Column J for KMPi Systems

            ' KR2i Systems Category
            Case poi = "KrosFlo KR2i TFF System", poi = "KR2i Systems", _
                 poi = "Small-Scale Systems", poi = "SYR2-U30", _
                 poi = "KrosFlo KR2i", poi = "Small Scale Systems"
                col = 11 ' Column K for KR2i Systems
            
            ' KRM Chromatography Systems Category
            Case poi = "Chromatography Systems", poi = "KRM Chromatography Systems", _
                 poi = "KRM™ Chromatography Systems", poi = "KRM Chromatography System"
                col = 12 ' Column L for KRM Chromatography Systems
            
            ' KTF Systems Category
            Case poi = "KTF Systems", poi = "KrosFlo KTF TFF Systems"
                col = 13 ' Column M for KTF Systems
            
            ' Mutliproduct Category
            Case poi = ";", poi = ","
                col = 14 ' Column N for Mutliproduct
            
            ' None Category
            Case poi = "None", poi = "Blank Cell"
                col = 15 ' Column O for None
            
            ' OPUS Category
            Case poi = "OPUS", poi = "OPUS 2.5 - 80R", _
                 poi = "OPUS Pre-packed Chromatography Columns", poi = "OPUS 2.5 - 80R Pre-packed Columns"
                col = 16 ' Column P for OPUS
            
            ' OPUS PD Category
            Case poi = "OPUS PD", poi = "OPUS MiniChrom", _
                 poi = "OPUS Robo", poi = "OPUS Mini", _
                 poi = "OPUS RoboColumn", poi = "OPUS Vali", _
                 poi = "OPUS ValiChrom", poi = "OPUS Mini;OPUS Robo;OPUS Vali;OPUS PD", _
                 poi = "OPUS Robo;OPUS RoboColumn", poi = "OPUS Mini;OPUS PD", _
                 poi = "OPUS Robo;OPUS PD"
                col = 17 ' Column Q for OPUS PD
            
            ' Other Category
            Case poi = "Protein A Ligands", poi = "TFF Downstream", _
                 poi = "Ligands", poi = "Upstream Filtration", _
                 poi = "NGL-Impact A Ligand", poi = "TFF Systems", _
                 poi = "Operating Room Disposables", poi = "Gene Therapy", _
                 poi = "Large-Scale Systems", poi = "Downstream Filtration", _
                 poi = "TFF Upstream", poi = "KrosFlo TFF Systems", _
                 poi = "STUBEGN15390S"
                col = 18 ' Column R for Other
            ' ProConneX Category
            Case poi = "ProConneX", poi = "ProConnex Flow Paths for Systems", _
                 poi = "ProConnex Flow Paths"
                col = 19 ' Column S for ProConneX
            
            ' Resins Category
            Case poi = "CaptivA Protein A Affinity Resin", poi = "AVIPure AAV Affinity Resins", _
                 poi = "Resins", poi = "Avitide", poi = "100AAV9-1000", _
                 poi = "Custom Affinity Resin Development", poi = "Avititde Resins", _
                 poi = "Avitide Resins", poi = "NGL COVID-19 Spike Protein Affinity Resin", _
                 poi = "100AAV9-25"
                col = 20 ' Column T for Resins
            
            ' RPM Systems Category
            Case poi = "KR2i RPM System", poi = "KR2i + FlowVPX Integrated TFF System", _
                 poi = "FS-15 RPM System"
                col = 21 ' Column U for RPM Systems
            
            ' RS Systems Category
            Case poi = "KrosFlo RS TFF Systems"
                col = 22 ' Column V for RS Systems
            
            ' SoloVPE Category
            Case poi = "SoloVPE"
                col = 23 ' Column W for SoloVPE
            
            ' TangenX Category
            Case poi = "TangenX Flat Sheet Cassettes", poi = "TangenX", _
                 poi = "TangenX Hardware", poi = "TangenX SIUS TFF Cassettes", _
                 poi = "TangenX Flat Sheet Membranes", poi = "TangenX PRO Cassettes", _
                 poi = "TangenX SC", poi = "TangenX SIUS Gamma TFF Devices"
                col = 24 ' Column X for TangenX
            
            ' TFDF Category
            Case poi = "TFDF", poi = "TFDF Systems"
                col = 25 ' Column Y for TFDF
            
            ' ViPER Software Category
            Case poi = "ViPER Software"
                col = 26 ' Column Z for ViPER Software
            
            ' VPT Consumables Category
            Case poi = "VPT Consumables"
                col = 27 ' Column AA for VPT Consumables
            
            ' XCell Category
            Case poi = "XCell ATF Systems", poi = "XCell", _
                 poi = "XCell ATF Devices and Controllers", poi = "XCell™ Lab System", _
                 poi = "Xcell ATF", poi = "XCell ATF System", _
                 poi = "SU XCell", poi = "XCell;TFF Upstream"
                col = 28 ' Column AB for XCell
        End Select
        
        ' Paste the POI in the corresponding column if a category was found
        If col > 0 Then
            wsPOIBuckets.Cells(wsPOIBuckets.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = poi
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Inform the user that the sorting is complete
    MsgBox "Sorting completed!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by putting a breakpoint on the start of the loop. Then run it and use `F8` to step through it and watch the decisions it makes.

Comment: I think you're not using Select Case correctly.  You want something like `Select Case poi<\n> Case "Dialysis", "SpectraFlo™ Dynamic Dialysis Systems" <\n>  col = 1`

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `but is not shorting with right categorization`. `If col > 0 Then` uses `col` to determine the destination column. The varible `col` should be reset at the beginning of each looping.  Insert `col = 0` before `Select Case True`.

Comment: ...or add a Case Else at the end

Comment: That whole `Select Case` would be better as a lookup table (Term, Column Number) on a worksheet

Comment: For example, assuming `col = 5` in the first round loop. If `poi` doesn't meet any case conditions in the second round loop, and `col` remains as 5 (without being reset), then `poi` is incorrectly written to col 5.

Comment: @taller sorry, I meant sorting. Meaning, I want to have certain types sorted under certain categories.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you. Would you have an example of that? That sounds much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already got an answer to the specific problem you were having, but following on from my comment about using a lookup table in place of that huge `Select Case`:

Lookup table on sheet (eg) "RefTable":

[image]

Modified code:

```
Sub SortDataIntoPOIBuckets()
    
    Dim wsLeadData As Worksheet, wsPOIBuckets As Worksheet, wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, poi As String, res, m
    
    Set wsLeadData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lead Data")
    Set wsPOIBuckets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POI Buckets")
    Set wsRef = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RefTable")
    
    ' Clear previous data from POI Buckets starting from row 2
    wsPOIBuckets.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
    
    ' Loop through each row in Lead Data
    For i = 2 To wsLeadData.Cells(wsLeadData.Rows.count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
        
        poi = wsLeadData.Cells(i, "X").Value 'product from column X
        If Len(poi) > 0 Then
            res = Application.VLookup(poi, wsRef.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        
            If Not IsError(res) Then 'got a match?
                m = Application.Match(poi, wsPOIBuckets.Columns(res), 0) 'poi already in this column?
                If IsError(m) Then 'add if not already present
                    wsPOIBuckets.Cells(wsPOIBuckets.Rows.count, res).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = poi
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Unmatched: " & poi
            End If
        End If 'poi not blank
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to have done it. One thing I noticed is that where multiple lookups, e.g.: more than one product that should show in a column, it only shows the first.

Also, can I ask one more question? Is there a way to automatically dedupe each column?

Comment: Example, I'd add a picture, but it won't let do that here. The final output would be

Column 1

Dialysis
>Dialysis
>SpectraFlo™ Dynamic Dialysis Systems
>SpectraPor Tubing Closures
>Dialysis;SpectraFlo™ Dynamic Dialysis Systems
>SpectraPor Float-A-Lyzer
>SpectraPor Micro Float-A-Lyzer

Column 2
ELISA
>ELISA
>ELISA Kits


Not sure if that helps.

Comment: See edit for de-duping within any given bin column.  I'm not following your other question.  Aren't you looking for an exact match for each poi?

Comment: Tim, would be happy to send you an email to see what I have done so far if that would help. You can email at brian@digitalexecutive.io if you wanted to email me. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Group Data

```
Sub SortDataIntoPOIBuckets()
    
    ' Set references to the workbook and worksheets.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsLeadData As Worksheet: Set wsLeadData = wb.Sheets("Lead Data")
    Dim wsPOIBuckets As Worksheet: Set wsPOIBuckets = wb.Sheets("POI Buckets")
    Dim wsCategories As Worksheet: Set wsCategories = wb.Sheets("Categories")
    
    ' Return the values from sheet 'Categories' in an array.
    
    Dim Categories() As Variant, ccCount As Long
    
    With wsCategories.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Categories = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        ccCount = UBound(Categories, 2)
    End With
    
    ' Return the values from the 'Categories' array in a dictionary.
    
    Dim dictCategories As Object:
    Set dictCategories = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictCategories.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Category As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Categories, 1)
        For c = 1 To ccCount
            Category = Categories(r, c)
            If Not IsError(Category) Then
                If Len(Category) > 0 Then dictCategories(Category) = c
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Return the values in column 'X' of sheet 'Lead Data' in an array.
    
    Dim LeadData() As Variant, lrCount As Long
    
    With wsLeadData
        LeadData = .Range("X2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp))
        lrCount = UBound(LeadData, 1)
    End With
    
    ' Define the 'POIBuckets' array.
    Dim POIBuckets() As Variant: ReDim POIBuckets(1 To lrCount, 1 To ccCount)
    
    Dim Poi As String, lr As Long, pr As Long, pc As Long
    
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        Poi = CStr(LeadData(lr, 1))
        If dictCategories.Exists(Poi) Then
            pc = dictCategories(Poi) ' read column from dictionary
            pr = POIBuckets(lrCount, pc) + 1 ' read row from last row of array
            POIBuckets(pr, pc) = Poi ' write POI to current row of array
            POIBuckets(lrCount, pc) = pr ' write current to last row of array
        End If
    Next lr
    
    With wsPOIBuckets.Range("A2").Resize(pr, ccCount)
        .Value = POIBuckets
        .Resize(wsPOIBuckets.Rows.Count - .Row - pr + 1).Offset(pr).ClearContents
    End With
    
    ' Inform the user that the sorting is complete
    MsgBox "Sorting completed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help below. Your model was easy to setup. The one thing that I continue to get on each of the options I've tried is that it is not pulling in the different options under each category. Rather it is just pulling in the first and then running that first option a series of time (e.g.: not deduping). I did send you an email to the gmail.com address on your profile in case seeing it would make it easier to see. 

Any ideas if there is something I can change on the code. 

I appreciate all the help. I'd add a file, but not sure I can do that here.

Comment: Below (after) `pc = dictCategories(Poi)` use `dictCategories.Remove Poi`.